# Surjective and injective - example $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the definitions of surjective and injective, but I thought of an example:

- We have a mapping $\mathbb{R}^4 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$. This mapping canot can be surjective. It cannot be injective.

Correct?

Comment: What is the map? How is it defined?

Comment: It can surely be surjective. It can be bijective. It can be linear and surjective, but it can't be linear and injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it can't be injective since they have different dimensions. However, it can be surjective. For example, consider $\phi : \mathbb{R}^4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $\phi(x, y, z, t) = (x, y, z)$. It's surjective but not injective.

However, if you are looking for a function from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, then there exists a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ (in fact from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, with $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$) and hence the function you're looking for exists.

On the other hand, if you want a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, in 1911 Brouwer showed that there are no homeomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.